# Finding text node availability in xml

Tags: xslt

Hi all
    I am using xslt1.0, i want to find whether the node  present inside a xml file or not.It may be as parent, child or anywhere.Is there any xpath or function to find it..
Please help me..Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems you obviously need to formulate your questions better and ask someone who knows English to write them for you. Give examples and make sure that your questions are understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if a specific node is present ANYWHERE in the document. You can just use `//nodename` which will return a nodeset of all Nodes named "nodename" anywhere in the document.

hope that helps.

Comment: but how to use this as xslt template?

Comment: <xsl:template match="//nodename">

Comment: Starting `//` operator in patterns is not needed.